# Call 'npm init' via execSync in Node.js application, and automatically enter required console input

Tags: node.js, exec, prompt

I'm writing a Node application that automatically spins up new templated Node applications (with various configurations), including executing the 'npm init' step, but this is failing because npm init requires multiple follow-up inputs from the user.

This is what I'm executing so far, and it never completes:

```
execSync('cd ' + targetFolder + '; npm init;');
```

Is it possible for me to provide an array of Strings (empty or otherwise) to sequentially be input automatically when prompted?

Comment: Unless you actually _want_ to go through the choices, why not use `--yes`? In many cases init just creates a package file, which you could do more directly anyway.

Comment: If you want to give inputs, just write to npms stdin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jonrsharpe. Just executing 'npm init --yes' achieves what I wanted.